# How to whitelist certain colours in a pygame surface

Tags: python, pygame, surface

is there a way to whitelist colours on a surface in pygame and any colour that is not in that whitelist becomes transparent?

ive tried to use `icon.set_colorkey()` but that only removes one colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it manually Ensure that format of the image has an alpha channel by [`pygame.Surface.convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha). Identify all the pixel, which have a red green and blue color channel above a certain threshold (e.g. 230). Change the color channels and the alpha channel of those pixels to (0, 0, 0, 0):

```py
img = pygame.image.load(IMAGE).convert_alpha()

threshold = 230
for x in range(img.get_width()):
    for y in range(img.get_height()):
        color = img.get_at((x, y))
        if color.r > threshold and color.g > threshold and color.b > threshold:
            img.set_at((x, y), (0, 0, 0, 0))
```